# Given 4 persons, how many possibilities that in each triplet there will be both friends and strangers?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am asking for tips to following question:

Given 4 persons, how many possibilities that in each triplet there will be both friends and strangers?

I've tried to count drawing all possibilities, for 3 persons it is pretty clear - there will be 6 such possibilities, but I'm stuck drawing this for 4 persons, because there are clearly dependend sides for two triplets.

Is there any other way to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: isn't that the same as graph without triangles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In how many ways can we color the edges of a labeled $K_4$ red and blue such that there is no unicolored triangle?

It can not be done with $0$, $1$, $5$ or $6$ red edges. It can be done in $3$ ways each with two  red edges or with two blue edges. Three red edges will have to form a propeller (which leads to a blue triangle, whence is forbidden) or a path of length three. The middle edge of this path can be chosen in $6$ ways; then we can choose the left edge in $2$ ways,  and this enforces the choice of the third edge. The blue edges will then automatically form a path of length three as well. In all there are $6\cdot2=12$ possibilities with three red edges, giving a total of $18$ possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the people, A, B, C and D.

Among A, B and C there must be either two pairs of friends or two pairs of strangers and one of the three people must have the same relationship with both of the others.  So there are $6$ possibilities.

Arbitrarily suppose A is friends with B and C but B and C are strangers to each other.  A must then be a stranger to D (otherwise there is either a triangle of friends involving A and D, or B, C and D are all strangers to each other). You cannot have B a stranger to D and C a stranger to D (B, C and D would all be strangers to each other), so there are $3$ possibilities remaining for the combined relationships between B and D and between C and D.

$6 \times 3=18.$

Comment: Thanks! It's pretty interesting, how many there are possibilities for 5 persons? For 6 persons, as I can see, there won't be any such possibility, because there will be always triangle of friends or strangers.